Manipulate text layer in searchable PDF file with python
I have a workflow where I scan documents and automatically OCR these documents so that I get a searchable PDF file. I am using a python script and the PDF24 command line interface to achieve that task. So far so good. Now I would like to postprocess the searchable PDF file. Specifically I want to remove any double spaces inside the text layer (and replace them with single spaces). The appearance of the PDF file should not be changed at all though. The image should remain the same and only the (transparent) text layer should be altered.
I have tried it with this python script:
from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfWriter, PdfDict, PdfString
import re

def clean_text_in_stream(stream):
    """Remove unnecessary double spaces within a PDF content stream."""
    # Regex pattern to match text spans within parentheses
    def replace_double_spaces(match):
        text = match.group(0)
        return re.sub(r' {2,}', ' ', text)

    # Replace double spaces within text blocks
    return re.sub(r'\(([^()]*)\)', replace_double_spaces, stream)

def process_pdf(input_path, output_path):
    # Read the PDF
    reader = PdfReader(input_path)
    writer = PdfWriter()

    # Iterate through the pages
    for page in reader.pages:
        # Access the page's content
        contents = page.Contents

        # Handle cases where there may be multiple content streams
        if isinstance(contents, list):
            for i in range(len(contents)):
                stream = contents[i].stream
                cleaned_stream = clean_text_in_stream(stream)
                contents[i].stream = PdfString(cleaned_stream)
        else:
            stream = contents.stream
            cleaned_stream = clean_text_in_stream(stream)
            contents.stream = PdfString(cleaned_stream)

        writer.addpage(page)

    # Write the modified PDF to the output file
    writer.write(output_path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_pdf = r"C:\example.pdf"
    output_pdf = r"C:\example_no_double_spaces.pdf"
    process_pdf(input_pdf, output_pdf)

The script returns no errors and creates the output PDF file. However, the resulting PDF file still has all the double spaces in it. Why is that?
I am open to any suggestions that might achieve the task that I described. Do I need to use different libraries?
Thank you for your help.

After some investigation, I discovered that the problem with the double spaces wasn't related to the PDF content itself, but rather how a specific PDF viewer (PDF-XChange Viewer/Editor) interprets and processes the text when it's selected and copied. I did not have the same problem with any other PDF viewer.
